# A simple question concerning the verb « brancher »

Tags: verbes

[Le Robert states that one of the definitions of *« brancher »* is](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/brancher)

[image]

I’m a bit confused. So does the sentence « Je branche qn. » mean

(a) “I’m walking up to sb in order to talk to them.”

or

(b) “I’m flirting with sb.”

or

(c) “I’m walking up to be sb in order to flirt with them.”

Which is it?:/

Answer (score 3):

*Brancher* can mean "to hit on someone" but it is not necessarily flirting, maybe just trying to engage in an unsolicited conversation with someone.

Comment: Please note that if Juliette is saying to a friend "Julien, il me branche", she could not necessarily mean "Julien is hitting on me", it could also mean "I'm interested in Julien", in which case it corresponds to the definition number 3 in the source the OP mentionned.

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes, that would be an ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 1):

*Brancher quelqu'un* definitely has a seduction connotation to it, so your proposition (c) is almost correct. You can omit the "walking up to someone" part though, as you could very well "brancher quelqu'un" by message or eye contact.

More generally, "être branché par quelque chose" means to be attracted / looking forward to do something, as in "Ça me brancherait bien d'aller au ciné ce soir".

Whatever the context, it is considered familiar language that may not be appropriated to any situation.